# Reordering table rows using UITableViewDataSource methods does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to play a reorder animation that should be called by the methods below, I guess

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    
}
```

But for some reason, no animation followed. Most likely, I missed something, how exactly to trigger the animation of changing the order of the cells.

Comment: Welcome to SO! But your question cannot be answered as it is. You had e.g. to provide your animation code so that one can check what might wrong.

Comment: You have to rearrange your data source

Answer (score 0):

I found the missing component. The reason for which the animation of moving cells did not start. It's the lack of a setting:

```
tableView.isEditing = true
```